# How can i make this run faster? it takes 1 min to run

Tags: python, for-loop

So im working on a project, but the run time is preaty slow. I was wondering if there is any way to make this part of the code run any faster?

```
for i in image[start:end-1]:
    L = main(i)
    for j in range(len(L)):
         length.append(L[j])
```

Comment: How big is the image list ?

Comment: This is not enough information to try to optimize the code. Apart from using list comprehension, there are not many things to optimize here. The bottleneck is most probably in the `main` function or your `image` list is veeeery big

Comment: Don't use `for i in range(len(XXX))`. Use `for index, item in enumerate(XXX)`.Then you can use `length.append(item)`. Thist is probably not really faster, but way better cor readability and code quality.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.